# running a .sh file inside grails server

Tags: java, grails, groovy, io

I am trying to run a bash file(.sh) to make some photos conversion in my grails server, my code is the following to make that task:

```
        def folderTo = grailsAttributes.getApplicationContext().getResource("/files/").getFile()
        def f = new File(folderFrom.toString())
        def cmd = '/bin/bash /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/malibueventapp-qa/uploads/convertPhoto.sh /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/malibueventapp-qa/uploads /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/malibueventapp-qa/files'
        def process = runtime.exec(cmd, null, f);
```

the problem here is, when I am running it in the server, I am getting the follow error:

```
Cannot run program "/bin/bash" (in directory "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/malibueventapp-qa/uploads"): java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory
```

that is the only message error i am getting! so I have no ideas what to do!

some sugestions?!

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're not alone:

[How to solve "java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory" calling Runtime#exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124771/how-to-solve-java-io-ioexception-error-12-cannot-allocate-memory-calling-runt)

Above SO thread provides a (possible) solution to your problem, give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

just to sum-up what I did!

I increased the swap memory: http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442430-increase-your-available-swap-space-with-a-swap-file

and also runned:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

cheers!