# Play! framework. IOException

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, web-development-server

I am new with Play! framework and in the process of learning.
so, I'm building this dummy site and all of a sudden I get this message:

> IOException: Cannot run program "javac": java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory

I got the latest jdk on my machine, and got enough RAM to allocate as far as I know...

where is the problem?
thanks

Comment: And take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124771/how-to-solve-java-io-ioexception-error-12-cannot-allocate-memory-calling-run

Comment: BUT,
I got 4GB RAM so how is it possible?

Comment: @socksocket I posted an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777210/playframework-ioexception-unable-to-allocate-memory that might interest you. Reducing the amount of memory allocated to the JVM by play will probably solve your issue.