# how to reproduce java.io.IOException exception for Runtime.exec()?

Tags: java, exception, runtime.exec

At times, I get "java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory" in my java application.

I want to reproduce it on my machine.
Is there a way to reproduce this error? When will Runtime.exec throw java.io.IOException?

FYI,
[root@ara ~]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Why you need to reproduce this? It seems to be a bug.

Comment: I want to reproduce it, to test my exception handling code. I need to test the code path of exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124771):

1. Try it on an old OpenJDK version. It seems to be a JVM bug.
2. Set `overcommit_memory` to 2 (don't overcommit)

   `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`
3. Run the following program:

   ```
   public class ReproduceException {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
      }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've linked a question that explains what causes this problem and gives at least 2 ways to fix it.  From the explanation you should be able to figure out a strategy for causing it ... if that is still of interest after you've read the Q&A.