# Memory Allocated to Command Line Program Invoked through Java

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

Suppose I'm invoking a command line program through java using following code segment

```
 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
 p.waitFor();
```

In this case, how much memory will be allocated to `command` the program invoked by `exec`? Does it have anything to do with memory allocated for `jvm`? 
If so, How can I overcome this limitation?

**UPDATE**

According to an answer given for this question, [How to solve "java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory" calling Runtime#exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124771/how-to-solve-java-io-ioexception-error-12-cannot-allocate-memory-calling-run)

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec allocates the process with the same amount
>   of memory as the main. If you had you heap set to 1GB and try to exec
>   then it will allocate another 1GB for that process to run.

So is there any way by which, I can have more memory for the process that I'm invoking using java?

What if I run command through command prompt like this?

```
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c command");
```

In this case, who will decide memory limit? Command Prompt or Java?

Comment: Should be unrelated to JVM memory settings, and it is not limited by Java, either. Only OS-level per-process memory limits (for your user) apply.

Comment: @FranMontero
I'm asking about memory restriction. If memory allocated to program is limited by memory allotted to jvm, how can I overcome that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc for Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String) states that the command will be started in *a separate process*. Hence, the command itself will be run in its own process with its own memory and will not use any of the JVM memory.

However of course the method also returns a `Process` object, which itself will use a bit of the JVM memory, but that will be just a few variables to keep track of the process that was launched, so unless you start tens of thousands of processes in parallel this should not be an issue.